# Check if a number is a palindrome: if not sum the number and the number with reversed digits and continue checking

Tags: c

I´m learning C and doing the second task which is to check if an integer is a palindrome. If yes, I shall return the number; if not, I shall sum up the number and the number with reversed digits and check again.

Example:
Number: 195

- 195 + 591 = 786
- 786 + 687 = 1473
- 1473 + 3741 = 5214
- 5214 + 4125 = 9339 (is palindrome)

If the program has checked 20 times and it´s still not a palindrome, I shall return 0.

My program looks like this:

```
int addRev(int n) {
    int count;
    int reversed = 0;
    int remain;
    int original;
    original = n;
    while (n != 0) {
        remain = n % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remain;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (original==reversed){
        return original;
    }
    else{
        original+=reversed;
    }
    return original;
}
```

I have checked the program so far. If I test it with 191, it's a palindrome and returns it. If I test with 195, it is not a palindrome and the function returns 786.

But what is the next step? Do I need a second while() to continue with 786?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by _'I shall return the digit'_. Does it mean you should return the input number if it appears palindromic?

Comment: Yes, if its palindrome, it returns the palindrome

Comment: You don't seem to have a loop that tries 20 times to see whether a number is a palindrome — and produces the reversed value etc.  You probably need two nested loops.  Or perhaps a couple of functions where one calls the other repeatedly.

Comment: The function that calls `addRev` should have a loop that calls `addRev` until either `addRev` returns the original number, or `addRev` has been called 20 times.

Comment: Note that 'a digit' refers to a number 0..9.  Your question refers to digit where it should probably refer to number.

Comment: Oh, I mixed up digit with number sry bad english

Answer (score 1):

The key is a requrement to make up to 20 tests.

So the algorithm may look like this

```
for i = 1 up to 20
{
    reversed = .......
    if original == reversed
        return original // it's a palindrome
    original += reversed
}
return 0 // no palindrome after 20 iterations
```